# Community Standards: Should Prices be Mentioned?

Tags: discussion

We are going to have a lot of gear talk on these forums. Done deal. And gear changes over time, so we might get some information rot. I wonder how we will handle that information rot, especially with the most variable piece of information: gear prices. I myself have answered [gear questions](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1938/buying-a-backpacking-knife/1969#1969) where I gave the prices for things.

But should we be giving prices for things at all?

**Cons**:
Prices vary a lot by city and country. And even if I chose the Amazon.com price, that will change in a year or two.

Pros:
On the other hand, even if the exact numbers for a price changes, perhaps the general scale of costs is useful. Or perhaps it is only useful if we just show the *difference* in prices between competing projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prices like this tend to go hand in hand for shopping questions, which are frowned upon in most scenarios - so I don't see this being a huge issue.

Where prices are mentioned, it tends to be much more vague - under $100, "budget", "willing to pay for quality", and so on. Despite being less specific I think these are actually much more useful, because they don't tend to rot over time and, like you say, give good comparisons.

Comment: Yes, you don't necessarily want to establish an all-out moratorium on mentioning prices, but specific pricing information should not be the focus of the post... but discussing *value* can sometimes provide important context.